# Select values for each example. year

Tags: sql

Example I have a Movies Table with, date of release and lenght.
I need to Select year of release and the average movie lenght for each year individually in descending order.

I have no idea I started with this:

`SELECT YEAR(dateOfRelease), AVG(Lenght) FROM Movies WHERE ...`

I know this is probably a simple select query but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hint: ORDER BY dateOfRelease DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `GROUP BY` clause to aggregate result by years and use `ORDER BY` clause to order result set, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(dateOfRelease) AS year, 
  AVG(Length) AS avg_length
FROM Movies 
# WHERE ... put your conditions here
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY avg_length DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use GROUP BY here:

```
SELECT YEAR(dateOfRelease), AVG(Lenght) FROM Movies
GROUP BY YEAR(dateOfRelease)
```